# Find all cell containing a substring and add them

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add all cells that contains the word "WAGES" If a cell in column G contains the word "WAGES" the amount(column j) will be displayed. If there's 2 or more cells containing "WAGES" then their respective amounts will be added. Here's my code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As String, name As String
Dim a As Double, b As Double

x = "WAGES"
i = 3
Do Until Sheets("SHIPNET").Cells(i, 7) = ""
    name = Sheets("SHIPNET").Cells(i, 7)

    If InStr(1, name, x, 1) Then

        a = Sheets("SHIPNET").Cells(i, 10).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If

    If InStr(1, name, x, 1) Then

        b = Sheets("SHIPNET").Cells(i, 10).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If

i = i + 1
Loop

Sheets("MACRO TEMPLATE").Cells(5, 3) = a + b
```

My code is only limited to 2 cell that contains "WAGES". Is there anyway to make it dynamic instead of finding 2 cells only?

In the picture's case, -28,622.20 and -50,372.64 will be added.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a `SUMIF` with wildcards?
One line of code to replace the whole thing.

```
Sheets("MACRO TEMPLATE").Cells(5, 3) = worksheetfunction.SumIf(Sheets("SHIPNET").Range("G:G"),"*WAGES*",Sheets("SHIPNET").Range("J:J"))
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working. I just changed worksheetfunction.SumIf to Application.SumIf. But what if my substring is "WAGES" or "WAGE"?

Comment: make it *WAGE*. there should be asterisks around that, the forum removed them

Comment: There's an instance where I'll find cells that has either "WAGES" or "WAGE". How can I do that. I'm finding cell that has "WAGES" or "WAGE" Thanks for answer my questions by the way.

Comment: Oh so you want two separate amounts? First is wages then second is wage minus the first amount

Comment: No, sometimes, column G doesn't have the word "WAGES" but have "WAGE" so I would like to have "WAGE" and "WAGES" as the basis for finding the cell.

Comment: I'm confused, if you use wage with an asterisk on each side it will find wages too because wage exists inside the word wages

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've decided to stick with the word "WAGE" I've realized that the word "WAGES" contains "WAGE" so It won't be a problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yea, my mistake, I've realized that too late. Thanks.